# Can files be renamed within Droid Explorer

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, droid-explorer

I want to rename `otacerts.zip` in a KitKat install on an LG G2 LS980 ZVD and can see no way to do this within Droid Explorer.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

*As the Developer of Droid Explorer*:

If the file lives in a location on the file system that is mounted as readonly you will not be able to rename a file. This is for security reasons. The same thing goes for deleting a file. This is something I look to address in the future, but have not found the best solution to allow this safely yet.

Otherwise; you can select the file, and click F2 to rename. Or select the file and click it a second time. There is not a menu item to do this action, which there probably should be, I will get that into the work items and prioritized.